# SSIS 2017 - Parse flat file with multiple columns and headers on multiple lines

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, ssis-2017

I receive a daily CSV file that contains 600+ company employee positions, each of which are formatted as follows:

```
Position,Description
SUP1015,Shipping Supervisor Day
Work UOM:,Hours,Active:,Yes,Permanent:,Yes,,
Default Rate Level:,0,Default Rate Source:,Master,Default GL Source:,Master,,
Effective Date:,,Expiry Date:,,Created Date:,29-Apr-2014,Revised Date:,06-Jun-2019
Job Class:,,,,,Location:,,1004 - Shipping,,
Union Code:,,,,,Reports To:,,MGR1056 - Delivery & Shipping Manager,,
Position FTE:,,1.0000,,,,,,
```

My goal is to transform all 600+ records into one table:

```
Position | Description                     | Work UOM | Active | Permanent | Default Rate Level | Default Rate Source | Default GL Code | Effective Date | Expiry Date | Created Date | Revised Date | Job Class | Location                 | Union Code | Reports to                                    | Position FTE |
=========================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
SUP1015  | Shipping Supervisor Day         | Hours    | Yes    | Yes       | 0                  | Master              | Master          |                |             | 29-Apr-2014  | 06-Jun-2019  |           | 1004 - Shipping          |            | MGR1056 - Delivery & Shipping Manager         | 1.0000       |
```

I have no idea how to parse this, given the connection managers in SSIS.  Any help and guidance is greatly appreciated.